# soap function not returning string in php

Tags: php, curl, soap, server, client

I have a script which return a string in below format

```
 {"showStatus":[{"large":980,"small":200,"title":"New Arrival<\/span>gothrough:   Red","status":6,"Id":87643}],"totalStatus  kers":2}1
```

I have curl code which get this data from other site after login. I am developing a soap server to share this detail with other servers as well instead of again login and get this data. but I am not getting this data on other server through soap client. My code for soap server is

```
<?php

 $server = new SoapServer(null,
                     array('uri' => "urn://mytest/result"));

 function get_data()
 {
 $cookie = 'cookie.txt';
 $url1="http://example.com/city/getdata/";
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X     10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112   Safari/534.30');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
return $result;
}

$server->addFunction('get_data');
$server->handle();
?>
```

and soap client on other server is having this code

```
 $client = new SoapClient(null, array(
  'location' => "http://x.x.x.x/soapserver/soapserver.php",
  'uri'      => "urn://mytest/result"));

 $result = $client->
    __soapCall("get_data");

echo $result;
?>
```

I am getting output of "1" instead of that string. Please comment if you know any error in this

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to get the result on success.

Add this line before `curl_exec`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

> **curl_exec()** returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result
>   on success, FALSE on failure.